# How to select columns in a dataframe where column names are of datetime dtypes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have the following example table:

```
cols = ['2000-01-01', '2000-02-01', '2001-03-01', '2001-04-01', '2002-05-01']
vals = np.arange(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[vals], columns=cols)
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
```

How could select all columns for a particular year or month?

As an example, I tried the following for the year 2000

```
df.loc[:,'2000']
```

but got a key error

thanks!

Comment: I left out 1 additional command in the original dataframe to convert the string colum names to date time:
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single row:

```
>>> df.loc[0, '2000']
2000-01-01    0
2000-02-01    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

If you want multiple rows:

```
>>> df
   2000-01-01  2000-02-01  2001-03-01  2001-04-01  2002-05-01
0           0           1           2           3           4
1           0           1           2           3           4
>>> df.T['2000'].T

   2000-01-01  2000-02-01
0           0           1
1           0           1
```

Or go with exact indexing:

```
>>> df.loc[:, datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1): datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 31)]
   2000-01-01  2000-02-01
0           0           1
1           0           1
```

Comment: thank you! I found a more complicated solution as well:
df.loc[:, df.columns.year==2000]

but yours is much simpler

Answer (score 0):

You can select columns by regex using [pandas.DataFrame.filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```py
df.filter(regex=('2000.*')) # 2000-01-01, 2000-02-01
```

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are in `Timestamp` format:

```py
df[[c for c in df.columns if c.year == 2000]]
```

This is the output with the data in your example:

```sh
   2000-01-01  2000-02-01
0           0           1
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.loc` and create a timestamp object to use for a comparison boolean.

```
df.loc[:,df.columns > pd.Timestamp('01 Jan 2000')]
   2000-02-01  2001-03-01  2001-04-01  2002-05-01
0           1           2           3           4


df.columns > pd.Timestamp('01 Jan 2000')
array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try also so called 'boolean indexing', I think it has a clear syntax to understand :
`df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains("2000")]`

Output:

```
       2000-01-01  2000-02-01
   0           0           1
```